# VBScript keeps turning errors such as declaration expected on line 10 and others

Tags: vbscript, scripting, wsh

I seem to be having some problems on line 10 there. There are probably other errors as well. I've run debug to try and isolate the problems, any help is greatly appreciated.

```
Option Explicit On
Dim fso

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

FSO.CopyFile "C:\Users\usr\Desktop\UMAD.vbs", "C:\Users\Public\Music\"
FSO.CopyFile "C:\Users\usr\Desktop\DVD.vbs", "C:\Users\Public\Documents\"
FSO.CopyFile "C:\Users\usr\Desktop\back.vbs", "C:\Users\Public\Videos\" 

Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Sub shell()
    Dim objShell
    Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )

    'run with wscript
    WshShell.Run("""C:\Users\Public\Music\UMAD.vbs"" ""C:\Users\Public\Music\UMAD.vbs""")

    WScript.Sleep 20000

    'run with cscript
    objShell.Run("""C:\Users\Public\Documents\DVD.vbs\"" ""C:\Users\Public\Documents\DVD.vbs\""")

    WScript.Sleep 5000

    'run with the default program for vbs files (usually cscript)
    objShell.Run("""C:\Users\Public\Videos\back.vbs""")
End Sub
```

Comment: There are a lot of place for improvement in this code.

Comment: 1. objShell and WshShell is the same thing. It does not need to be declared twice.
2. vbs should not call another vbs by going through the shell. Just call a sub from another vbs.
3. The source vbs does not need to be copied before being executed. Pass a path to the script as a parameter if you want to script to act on a specific folder.

Comment: @RegisDesrosiers *Just call a sub from another vbs.* VBScript doesn't support that.

Comment: Your Sub is actually a function because of the brackets. Nothing calls your sub so it never runs. Can you actually program?

Comment: @ACatInLove *Your Sub is actually a function because of the brackets.* Umm... no.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers yep, seems they have some gaps in their knowledge. Tried explaining that on the last question they shot me down on.

Comment: @ACatInLove as i said before i am rather new to vbs so calm down, thanks to everyone for the assisance

Answer (score 0):

One question, one answer. This answer belongs to the first problem "declaration expected on line 10."

If I count correctly, line 10 is `Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")`

The problem you are facing is, that all variables have to be declared when using `Option Explicit`. So you need to declare your `WshShell` like this:

```
Dim WshShell
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
```